# remove bottom layout scroll scrollview

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

> I want to remove scroll to button, when the keypad focussed, button has to stay at bottom of >layout, but its scrolling top of keypad. give me solution

Answer (score 0):

Set Window SoftInput Mode property to adjustPan and adjustResize to your activity:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"> </activity>
```